# Where to find Xamarin test recorder in visual studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I use Visual Studio . I use  Xamarin Cloud. I installed Test Recoder for VS.I do not see in the editor icon Test Recoder. How do I run Test Recoder for VS?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Test Recorder - Microsoft will discontinue development of Xamarin Test Recorder on macOS and the Visual Studio extension for Windows on March 31st, 2018. Upload to Test Cloud functionality from Xamarin Test Recorder will not be supported after this date. Moving forward, tests must be submitted through the Visual Studio App Center CLI.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/migration/test-cloud/#other-upcoming-product-changes

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you use the Community or Professional-Edition of Visual Studio. To use the Test Recorder you need the Enterprise-Edition of Visual Studio.

The download-page of the [Test Recorder](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/visual-studio/#Requirements) makes it clear:

> You will need a Visual Studio Enterprise subscription to use Test Recorder.

Comment: Yes i downloaded the same but still i am not able to find it.How to open the test recorder is there any shortcut key or how ?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using Visual Studio Enterprise ?

Comment: Yes it's Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.Version 14.0.25425.01.